# Как передать данные с помощью XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, xmlhttprequest

Не получается передать данные в action

```
function addComment() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', "/Picture/AddComment", true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
        if(this.readyState == 4) {
            if (this.status == 200) {
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
    request.send("comment=qwe");
}
```

тут comment = null

```
public IActionResult AddComment(string comment)
{
    return View("Index");
}
```

Comment: как вызывается `addComment` на клиенте?

Comment: <input type="button" onclick="addComment();" value="Add comment" />